# Forcing join in the query using JPA annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I'm struggling forcing Hibernate to use a join between two tables when fetching data. We have large parent table with a large child table, joined by multiple columns (there is no singular ID column). When we fetch the parent records, Hibernate eagerly fetches the children, but it does it with separate queries, one for each parent. This seems very slow compared to just one query with a join in it.

But how do you get Hibernate to do the join?

Here are the entities (this is just an anonymized example):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private BookID id;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "PUBLISH_DATE")
    private Date publishDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<BookReview> reviews;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK_REVIEWS")
public class BookReview
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private BookReviewID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "TITLE", referencedColumnName = "TITLE"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME", referencedColumnName = "AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_LAST_NAME", referencedColumnName = "AUTHOR_LAST_NAME")
    })
    private Book book;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE")
    private Date updateDate;
}
```

... and their embedded keys:

```
@Embeddable
public class BookID
{
    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME")
    private String authorFirstName;
    
    @Column(name = "AUTHOR_LAST_NAME")
    private String authorLastName;
}

@Embeddable
public class BookReviewID extends BookID
{
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String userName;
}
```

When I run a query for all records in `BOOK` (using `entityManager.createQuery("from Book")`), it runs a query on the BOOK table to fetch all the records, then separate queries for the reviews *of each record*. Rather than separate queries for each set of reviews for each book, it seems like it'd be a lot more efficient to just do a `left outer join` initially to get them.

Is this even possible through annotations? Or must I use the `CriteriaBuilder` or query language?

I should note that adding `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` doesn't change anything on what it seems to be doing under the covers.

Comment: Situations like that likely call for a [native sql query](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-direct-vs-query) strongly recommend to use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` instead of `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`:

> If you forget to `JOIN FETCH` all `EAGER` associations, Hibernate is going to issue a secondary select for each and every one of those which, in turn, can lead to N+1 query issues.
>
> For this reason, you should prefer LAZY associations.

So, I would suggest you to correct this association:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<BookReview> reviews;
```

to this:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<BookReview> reviews;
```

and then override the laziness of the joined association by using `join fetch` in the HQL like below:

```java
entityManager.createQuery(
  "select b from Book b join fetch b.reviews"
)
```

---

As for the `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`, as it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-join):

> The reason why we are not using a JPQL query to fetch multiple entities is because *the `FetchMode.JOIN` strategy would be overridden by the query fetching directive.*
>
> ...
>
> *Therefore, `FetchMode.JOIN` is useful for when entities are fetched directly, via their identifier or natural-id.*
>
> Also, the `FetchMode.JOIN` acts as a `FetchType.EAGER` strategy. Even if we mark the association as `FetchType.LAZY`, the `FetchMode.JOIN` will load the association eagerly.

So, `FetchMode.JOIN` will work only for the direct fetch like below:

```java
Book book = entityManager.find(Book.class, new BookID(...));
```

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. We have a ton of abstractions for the logic that invokes the `EntityManager` in order to make it generic and hidden from developers, but it looks like I'll have to change that part. Thanks!